# Permanently changing the range of the axes using matplotlib?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have been using pandas, matplotlib and seaborn for data visualisation but I can't figure out how to permanently change the axes limits? I will show you what I mean below: [image]

I want the y axis to go from 0 to 300 and the x axis from -4 to 4 (so that the background grid is complete, none of the squares are cut off).

In general I want the following:

Let the step on the y_axis be z (so 50 in the case above). Then, matplotlib automatically stops the y axis at y_max (maximum y value from the data). 
This y_max lands in between kz and (k+1)z, for some positive integer k (in the case above, it lands between 250 and 300, so 5*50 and 6*50, so k=5). Now, I want the y axis to stop at (k+1)z and not y_max.

And similarly for the x-axis.

I know that I can set the y limits and x limits manually for each plot, but is there a way I can somehow permanently get matplotlib/pandas/seaborn to automatically create the figures in such a way?

I tried looking at the rcParams on matplotlib but couldn't really see anything of use.

Comment: No, because it's unlikely than anyone will ever only create plots within a certain range, there is no global options for that. You have the option to set the limits for each plot though, `ax.set_xlim(..)`, or `ax.set(xlim=...)` or `ax.axis(...)`.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I didn't mean specifically for the above plot, that was just an example. I'm just not sure how to word the generalisation. I will edit my question for clarity.

Comment: I guess `plt.rcParams["axes.autolimit_mode"] = "round_number"` comes close to that.